# jquery, to manage the next elements

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

I am new to jquery and need your help to solve an issue. I am using jQuery Validation plugin to validate my forms. By default what this plugin do is it creates a label with class "errorMessage" if validation happens. Since the input tags do not allow ::before / ::after in CSS therefore to style my form I require some HTML element right after the inputs.

**PROBLEM:**
The  Plugin pushes down that HTML tag so that it can create its own "error" label right after the input tag.

**WHAT IS HAPPENING**

```
<input type="text" name="FirstName" class="inputField required">
<label class="errorMessage">Field is Required</label>
<div class="indicator"></div>
```

**WHAT I WANT**

```
<input type="text" name="FirstName" class="inputField required">
<div class="indicator"></div>
<label class="errorMessage">Field is Required</label>
```

To solve this issue i tried some code but it just adds more than one 'indicator class' in different scenarios

**MY SCRIPT**

```
// On Document Ready
// I need this indicator on all inputs by default.
$(".inputField").each(function(i, obj) {
    $(this).after('<div class="indicator"></div>');
});

// On Input Focus Event
$(".inputField").focus(function(){
    if($(this).next().hasClass('errorMessage')) { 
        $(this).after('<div class="indicator"></div>');
    }
});
```

**RESULTS**

```
<input type="text" name="FirstName" class="inputField required">
<div class="indicator"></div>
<label class="errorMessage">Field is Required</label>
<div class="indicator"></div>
```

How to stop the duplication of the 'indicator div" and if there is a smart way to write this code so that it renders fast.

Any help is highly appreciated, Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your `indicator` div for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered using the [errorplacement](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#errorplacement) callback?

The below should take the input element containing the validation error - `element` - and allow you to override where the error notification is created.

```
$("#id-of-your-form").validate({
  errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    error.appendTo(element.next(".indicator"));
  }
});
```

Then you can simply leave your HTML as:

```
<input type="text" name="FirstName" class="inputField required">
<div class="indicator"></div>
```

Comment: @timotgyclifford  thanks friend, it solved the issue.